# Why this space is not a complete space with this norm

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Show that the space $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ of all the real continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with compact support is not a complete space with the norm $||f||= \sup_{t∈ \mathbb{R}}|f(t)|$.

Thank you

Comment: It is better to denote it $C_c(\mathbb{R})$. This is a dense subspace of the Banach space $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ of continuous functions tending to $0$ at $\pm \infty$. Since $C_c\subsetneq C_0$, $C_c$ can't be complete, or it would be closed and dense...

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x) = \frac 1{1+x^2}$, define $f_n\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by $f_n(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in [-n,n]$, $f_n(x) = 0$ for $x \not\in [-n-1, n+1]$, affine-linear in between. Show that $(f_n)$ is Cauchy, but not convergent to some compact support function (as its limit in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is $f$).

Comment: $f_{n}(x)$ isn´t a continuous function you should change it for

Comment: @user73681 That's what I meant by "affine-linear in between".

Comment: That is ,for $n<x<n+1$ we let  $f_n(x)= (n+1-x)f_n(n),$ and similarly for $ -n-1<x<-n.$